# what is the difference between inner_join and semi_join?

Tags: r, dplyr

I could not understand difference between inner_join and semi_join? could you provide me with examples?

According to R

- semi_join() return all rows from x with a match in y.
- inner_join() only keeps observations from x that have a matching key in y.

Comment: http://statseducation.com/Introduction-to-R/modules/tidy%20data/joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rows from `x` returned by `semi_join()` and `inner_join()` are the same. The difference is that `inner_join` will add columns present in `y` but not present in `x`, but a `semi_join` will not add any columns from `y`.

```
x = data.frame(a = 1:3)
y = data.frame(a = 2:4, b = 10:12)

## with an inner join, the `b` column is part of the result
inner_join(x, y)
# Joining, by = "a"
#   a  b
# 1 2 10
# 2 3 11

## with a semi join, the `b` column is not part of the result
## because it is not part of `x`
semi_join(x, y)
# Joining, by = "a"
#   a
# 1 2
# 2 3
```

The joins documented together as *"mutating joins"*, which are described at `?inner_join` as

> mutating joins add columns from `y` to `x`, matching rows based on the key

Compare to the *"filtering joins"* documented together at `?semi_join`

> Filtering joins filter rows from `x` based on the presence or absence of matches in `y`

Filtering joins only filter `x`, they do not add columns from `y`.